# Wordpress and border images

Tags: image, wordpress, border

I need help with a wordpress website I'm working on currently. What I'm wanting to do is add an image border around the images. I have absolutely no idea how to do it and I'm a little bit confused! This is the code I have so far

```
.item_image {
width: 232px;
height: 170px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 40px;
border-image: url("/images/border.png") 30 30 30 30;
}
```

Below is the border image. If someone could give me a heads up on how to get this border around the image, I would be so grateful!

[image: here is the border image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it! Answer below :)

```
img {
box-shadow:none;
border-style: solid; 
border-width: 20px; 
-moz-border-image: url(images/border.png) 27 repeat; 
-webkit-border-image: url(images/border.png) 27 repeat; 
-o-border-image: url(images/border.png) 27 repeat; 
border-image: url(images/border.png) 27 fill repeat;    
}
```